# Why is AdSense not displaying ads on React Native web?

Tags: react-native, adsense, react-native-web

I have an empty space on my website that would be perfect for an ad because it's out of the functional area and won't ruin a user's experience. I've tried everything from creating my own component to using existing packages but nothing has worked. I am able to add the components and the page loads fine but an ad never shows. I added a border to the component which also does not show. Neither of the following components work.

In `Index.html`:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXX" ></script>
```

Using [`@ctrl/react-adsense`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ctrl/react-adsense):

```
          <Adsense
            client={"ca-pub-XXXX"}
            slot={"1234"}
            style={{ borderColor: "white", borderWidth: 2 }}
            format={"vertical, auto"}
            responsive={"true"}
          />
```

My custom component:

```
class AdComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const installGoogleAds = () => {
      const elem = document.createElement("script");
      elem.src =
        "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
      elem.async = true;
      elem.defer = true;
      document.body.insertBefore(elem, document.body.firstChild);
    };
    installGoogleAds();
    ((window as any).adsbygoogle = (window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        data-adtest="on"
        style={{ width: "90%", height: 300 }}
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"
        data-ad-slot="1234"
        data-ad-format="vertical, auto"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default AdComponent;
```

Comment: Do you see `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads` requests in network tab? How many? Also any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, there are two requests titled `ads` made to `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads`. No errors in the console. However, the network tab does show `An error occurred trying to load the resource Sodar: https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/sodar`.

Comment: Can you check whether ins element have `data-ad-status` attribute? If so - then ad request is working fine but for some reason no ad is returned. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10762946?hl=en

Comment: Also I would made sure that size of <ins> element is not 0.